# Long Text overlaps itself in Div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div box that I would like at a min-height: 33px; and word-wrap to increase the height, when greater than that height. Here's a fiddle that does work http://jsfiddle.net/PzfF7/! Any reasons it does this locally with only height:33px; :

[image] & (fiddle style)  [image]

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="messages">
        <div class="topMessage">
            new message that is really long and should be on multiple lines as this continues on to the next line and so on and so forth
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comments">
        <div class="comment">Here's a comment</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For whatever reason, setting the min-height: 33px; does not work, only height: 33px;.. And word-wrap or overflow-y: auto; (less preferable) don't work at all..

```
.outerDiv {
  width: 260px;
}
.messages {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 33px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: table;
  padding: 1%;
  font-size: 12.9px;
}
.topMessage {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 2%;
  font-size: 12.9px;
}
.comments {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 33px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 1%;
  display: table;
}
.comment {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  font-size: 12.9px;
}
```

Comment: the demo produces a fine result without any overlapping.

Comment: On which browser u r getting this output?

Comment: @KingKing Right, but what might be causing those screenshots?

Comment: Do you have `line-height: 0` anywhere on your local copy? Linking us to a _working_ copy doesn't really help us solve the problem...

Comment: @captainsac on safari, chrome, and firefox!

Comment: @ChristianVarga great call! That solves this.. Many thanks

Comment: Great news! Perhaps add it as an answer and accept it so other people searching for similar problems can find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

As @ChristianVarga pointed out: "Do you have line-height: 0 anywhere on your local copy?"

An inherited line-height: 0; was the interfering style.